# Как правильно строить алгоритм

Tags: java, алгоритм, список

**У меня есть задание и файл на вход, которые я прикреплю ниже. Я не совсе понимаю с чего начать...
Сейчас в голове у меня лишь рекурсия, правильно ли я думаю?**

*Дано расписание переездов поездов между несколькими станциями в формате “номер поезда;станция отправления;станция прибытия;стоимость;время отправления;время прибытия” (гарантированно, что нет переездов дольше суток) . Необходимо получить “лучшие” варианты (несколько, если это возможно) проезда с пересадками между всеми станциями. Запросы на лучшие варианты:*

- *Лучшие по цене*
- *Лучшие по времени*

Файл на вход:

```
2702;1902;1929;315.01;08:00:00;16:30:00
2703;1902;1929;315.01;08:00:00;16:30:00
2203;1902;1929;319.76;13:15:00;17:55:00
1405;1981;1929;330.59;17:40:00;16:21:00
4201;1929;1902;334.56;08:40:00;13:50:00
```

**Примечание к заданию!!!** Задача состоит в том чтобы найти лучшие маршруты для проезда с пересадками между всеми станциями. Например, у тебя есть 5 станций: 1,2,3,4,5. Ты находишь маршруты которые будут проходить через каждую станцию по одному разу и считаешь какие из них лучшие.

Comment: Ну, по цене вообще все просто - раз на время нет ограничений и можно ждать следующего поезда хоть сутки - обычный взвешенный граф...

Comment: по времени тоже всё просто. Для каждой станции смотрим момент когда раньше всего может туда попасть. По сути Дейкстра стандартная. Такая же как и по цене.

Comment: @Harry, если я правильно понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под взвешанным графом (через обход его алгоритмом [Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)), то оба варианта решаются одинаково, как вы и предложили: просто в качестве "веса" у ребер графа в одном случае использовать цену, а в другом время (как и предлагает @pavel), или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @pavel А как быть с учетом времени ожидания поезда? Или применять Дейкстру для каждой пары? Просто с ценой можно применить Флойда-Уоршелла и получить сразу, как и спрашивают, все минимальные цены; но со временем его вроде бы применить не удастся?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Для Дейкстры вроде бы да... Просто, как мне кажется, тут не получается непосредственное построение взвешенного графа - есть время не только в ребрах, но и ожидания на станции...

Comment: Тут ещё есть вот такое примечание. "Задача состоит в том чтобы найти лучшие маршруты для проезда с пересадками между всеми станциями. Например, у тебя есть 5 станций: 1,2,3,4,5. Ты находишь маршруты которые будут проходить через каждую станцию по одному разу и считаешь какие из них лучшие." Его я так же добавлю к заданию, чтоб все видели. Следовательно для этой задачи нужно реалзовать алгоритм Дейкстры?

Comment: @АнатолийКравченко, т.е. после этой правки ваша задача превращается в [задачу коммивояжера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0)?

Comment: Гм, я воспринял это условие не как искать путь по всем станциям. а как найти маршруты из каждой станции до каждой станции. Т.е. для всех 20 пар..

Comment: @StateItPrimitive вот думаю это то что нужно, но я не совсем понимаю, что именно брать за основу т.к. ранее не стакивался с таким алгоритмом

Comment: Тогда это полный перебор.

Comment: @Harry нет времени ожидания поезда. Есть время когда мы добираемся до следующей станции. Нам нету разницы мы ехали долго или ждали. В любом случае сохранён инвариант, если мы прибыли на станцию _раньше_ то мы прибудем на следующую _не позже_. Естественно это не для коммивояжёра задачи.

Comment: @pavel Если я правильно понимаю взвешенный граф, у него есть только вес ребра. Т.е. величина, по сути, зависящая только от двух вершин. Но Какой вес приписать для ребра AB, если потом я могу ехать в C сразу, а в D - еще ждать час? А если приезжаю EB - то в С ждать час, в D - сразу. Какой вес ребра BC? BD? Т.е., как мне кажется, описать ситуацию *только* взвешенным графом никак не получится.